# Migrating existing models to Wagtail Page models

Tags: wagtail

I am trying to use Wagtail in an existing Django project. I would like to migrate all existing models to corresponding new Wagtail Page models so that they can be exposed to the wagtail admin interface. For a test case I tried to create Page (StoryPage) model object by copying corresponding attributes from a non-page model (Story) using the db shell. As part of creating the new StoryPage object I set the 'path' and 'depth' attributes. But it still fails to create the StoryPage object. Would like to know if anyone has done this kind of migration. Love to see some code for doing such a migration.

Comment: Show your StoryPage code to help further on this question

Comment: class StoryPage(Page):
 body = RichTextField()
 date = models.DateField("Publish date")
 content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
  FieldPanel('date'),
  FieldPanel('body', classname="full"),
 ]

class Story(models.Model):
 title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
 body = models.TextField()
 date = models.DateField("Publish date")

Comment: `class StoryPage(Page):
 body = RichTextField()
 date = models.DateField("Publish date")
 content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
  FieldPanel('date'),
  FieldPanel('body', classname="full"),
 ]`